# How can I stop my recyclerview from allowing left swipe and only allow right swipe?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I'm using the example from https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/ to handle drag and swipe on a `RecyclerView`. It is working great except for I do not know how to stop it from allowing up/down/left swipes. I can ignore the swipes but I don't even want them to happen. Is that possible?

I even modified this code in the example I linked above to add `ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT` to the swipe flags but it didn't help.

```
@Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        // Set movement flags based on the layout manager
        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
            final int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT;
            final int swipeFlags = 0;
            return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
        } else {
            final int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
            final int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT ;
            return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I even modified this code in the example I linked above to add ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT to the swipe flags but it didn't help." It was the right direction, please post your modified code

Comment: The code is posted. Look at this line `final int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT ;` I also tested to make sure that code gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify

```
final int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT ;
```

to

```
final int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT ;
```

Comment: Thanks you, that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to android, so not sure if this will work for you, but it did for me.

I managed to do this by changing the `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` constructor (maybe try using the `SimpleCallback` instead of Callback which you're currently using?).

It used to say :

```
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = 
              new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | 
               ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT)
```

Now it says

```
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = 
             new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT)
```

Hope that helps.